# [System.IO.Path]::Combine not taking my powershell variable as a parameter?

Tags: powershell

Why isn't the function `[System.IO.Path]::Combine` taking my first parameter?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $g_basePath
F:\Dev\OneClickTools



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [Tests.Utils]::CUSTOMASSEMBLY_TEST
CustomLogic.dll



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [System.IO.Path]::Combine($g_basePath, "\bin\debug", [Tests.Utils]::CUSTOMASSEMBLY_TEST)
\bin\debug\CustomLogic.dll
```

The third command shows that only the second and third parameters were concatenated or is it using an empty string as `$g_basePath`..?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just *omit the leading backslash* on your second path:

```
[System.IO.Path]::Combine($g_basePath, "bin\debug", [Tests.Utils]::CUSTOMASSEMBLY_TEST)
```

---

A pure PowerShell attempt would be to use the [Join-path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) cmdlet twice:

```
Join-Path $g_basePath  'bin\debug' | Join-path -ChildPath [Tests.Utils]::CUSTOMASSEMBLY_TEST
```

Comment: ah thanks...I thought this sort of intelligence was built in the `[System.IO.Path]::Combine` function

Comment: thanks, I thought about using Join-Path...but having to use Join-Path twice is kind of sad :p

Answer (score 12):

To complement [Martin Brandl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37777377/45375):

Specifically, the - counter-intuitive - [logic applied by `[System.IO.Path]::Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784047(v=vs.110).aspx) is: "If *path2* or *path3* is also an absolute path, the combine operation discards all previously combined paths and resets to that absolute path." (this applies analogously to the other methods overloads too).

In other words: **the *last* path argument specified that starts with `\` (including `\\`) or `<letter>:` (a drive spec.) causes all previous paths to be *ignored*.**

```sh
PS> [IO.Path]::Combine('\foo', '\bar', '\baz')
\baz  # !! '\foo' and '\bar' were ignored
```

For the expected behavior - where an initial `\` should be treated as an optional part of each path component other than the first - ensure that every component but the first *doesn't* start with `\` - `Join-Path` handles that as one would expect.

A **simple function** can do that:

```sh
# Combines array of path components $a to a single path.
function combine([string[]] $a) {
  [IO.Path]::Combine([string[]] (@($a[0]) + $a[1..$($a.count-1)] -replace '^\\', '')) 
}
```

Note that casting to `[string[]]` is crucial for this to work.

Sample call:

```sh
PS> combine '\foo', '\bar', '\baz'
\foo\bar\baz  # as expected
```

---

Using **`Join-Path`**, which **only supports *pairs* of components** as of Windows PowerShell v5.1<sup>[1]</sup>
, an alternative to using a pipeline to chain multiple calls is to **nest multiple calls with `(...)`**:

```sh
PS> Join-Path \foo (Join-Path \bar \baz)
\foo\bar\baz
```

Note that even though the nesting is somewhat awkward, you do NOT need to worry about subordinate components that start with `\`.

---

**As for the logic of PowerShell's own `Join-Path` cmdlet**:

While it's understandable to expect the `-ChildPath` parameter to support an *array* of paths (which it doesn't), it's important to understand that **`Join-Path`'s design differs fundamentally from that of `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()`**, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1<sup>[1]</sup>
:

- **`Join-Path` uses multiple input paths to generate *multiple output paths*** rather than interpreting the input paths as components of a *single* output path.
- Input paths are ***pair(s)* of parent and child paths**, with each pair getting joined and resulting in its own output path:

  - `PS> Join-Path \foo \bar \foo\bar`

    - Short for: `Join-Path -Path \foo -ChildPath \bar`
    - Note how PS, unlike `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()`, handles an optional leading `\` in the child path as you would expect.
- While the parent-path parameter (`-Path`) *does* support an *array* of parent paths, the child-path parameter (`-ChildPath`) does *not*, although when combined with the `-Resolve` parameter and wildcards, it can effectively result in multiple child paths.

  - `PS> Join-Path -Path \foo, \baz -ChildPath \bar \foo\bar \baz\bar`
  - Note how *2* output paths were generated, by pairing each parent path with the one child path.
- Unlike `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()`, **`Join-Path` optionally supports resolving wildcard paths with `-Resolve`**:

  - `PS> Join-Path -Resolve C:\Win* Sys* C:\Windows\System C:\Windows\System32 C:\Windows\SystemApps C:\Windows\SystemResources C:\Windows\SysWOW64 C:\Windows\system.ini`
- Finally it's worth noting that `Join-Path` not only works with filesystem paths, but with the paths of any PowerShell [hierarchical data store] provider, applying the provider-appropriate path separators.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>
The ***cross-platform* PowerShell edition, *PowerShell Core***, as of v6.0.0, **already *does* support an arbitrary number of child components**, [**enabling calls such as `Join-Path a b c` to yield `a\b\c` (Windows) or `a/b/c` (Unix)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41769083/45375), whereas the Windows-native *Windows PowerShell* edition as of v5.1 still doesn't support it.
This new behavior is not yet documented (and not even reflected syntax-wise in `Join-Path -?`), but it may make its way into Windows PowerShell (and thereby *all* editions) eventually.