# Powershell to generate file paths correctly in windows and unix

Tags: windows, powershell, unix

I want to generate a string for a file path inside a powershell script. I want this to work in both in windows and mac.

At the moment the code is hardcoded to windows like paths ("\" -> windows, "/" -> unix):

`$templatep="$CoreRoot\templates\$serviceName"`

I changed this to:

`$templatep= Join-Path $CoreRoot "templates" $serviceName`

And it works in mac with Powershell 6.0. BUT it doesn't work in my windows server with Powershell 4. I have to do something like this:

`$templatep= Join-Path $CoreRoot -ChildPath "templates" | Join-Path -ChildPath $serviceName`

Any idea why this is just working in my mac? Is this a new feature in powershell 5 or 6?
I dont't like the having to pipe multiple Join-Paths. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Through PowerShell 5.0, to my knowledge `Join-Path` can only take two paths. Piping to another join or using .Net's `[io.path]::combine()` method are the two workarounds I know of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, a **workaround** using the .NET framework:

```sh
[IO.Path]::Combine('a', 'b', 'c')
```

This yields `a/b/c` on Unix, and `a\b\c` on Windows, and conveniently supports *any* number of path components.

Note:

- This workaround is only for *filesystem* paths, whereas `Join-Path` is designed to work with any PowerShell drive provider's paths.
- Make sure that no component other than the *first* starts with `\` (Windows) or `/` (Unix), because any preceding component is then ignored; e.g., on Windows:
  `[IO.Path]::Combine('\a', '\b', 'c')   # -> '\b\c' - '\a' is ignored(!)`
  Note that `Join-Path` does *not* exhibit this behavior; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37782461/45375) for details.

As an **alternative** to sequencing `Join-Path` calls with a *pipeline* you can simply **use `(...)`** (a subexpression):

```sh
Join-Path a (Join-Path b c)  # -> 'a\b\c' (on Windows)
```

---

The syntax displayed by `Join-Path -?` as of *Windows PowerShell* `v5.1.14393.693` (incidental parameters omitted):

```sh
Join-Path [-Path] <String[]> [-ChildPath] <String> ...
```

This syntax implies that **invocation `Join-Path a b c` results in a syntax error in *Windows PowerShell***, because there is no parameter to bind the `c` argument to.

By contrast, the syntax displayed in **PowerShell (Core) v6+** reveals an additional parameter:

```sh
Join-Path [-Path] <String[]> [-ChildPath] <String> [[-AdditionalChildPath] <String[]>]
```

It is the additional **`-AdditionalChildPath` parameter**, which is declared in a manner that collects all remaining positional arguments that (`ValueFromRemainingArguments`), that **makes specifying an arbitrary number of child components work**, so that **`Join-Path a b c` indeed works,** for instance.

Unfortunately, this enhancement [won't be back-ported](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/07/14/powershell-6-0-roadmap-coreclr-backwards-compatibility-and-more/) to Windows PowerShell.

Note that even though `[-Path] <String[]>` is an *array* parameter, its purpose is not to accept multiple child path components of a single output path, but to allow joining of *multiple* parent-child path pairs; e.g.:

```sh
$ Join-Path a,b c  # same as: Join-Path -Path a,b -ChildPath c
a\c
b\c
```

---

Finally, even **you can typically get away with hard-coding `/` as the path separator on *both* platforms**, because many Windows API functions as well as PowerShell's own cmdlets accept `\` and `/` *interchangeably*.
However, not all utilities may behave this way, so it's generally safer to use the platform-appropriate separator.

For instance, the following works just fine on Windows:

```sh
Get-Item c:/windows/system32 # same as: Get-Item c:\windows\system32
```