# Alternative to join-path to handle nonexistent drive

Tags: powershell

I made a function that creates a file name.

The function breaks when sent a drive letter that doesn’t exist.

I have have changed the function to not use join-path but I am wondering if there is another way?

The try / catch is not working as expected.

Perhaps the best answer is not using join-path ?

```
$fullPath = join-path -path $DirectoryName  -childpath ((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy_MM_ddThhmmss-') + ($ReportName + $Extension)) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()` perhaps? Show your code so we can help wit it,

Comment: I added a line of code. The forum would not allow me to add my entire function.

Comment: `code`
 $fullPath = $DirectoryName + '\' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyy_MM_ddThhmmss-') + ($ReportName + $Extension))
`code`
This is how I did it without the join-path and I was wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To **emulate [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path)'s behavior *without* the - surprising and vexing - requirement that a drive spec. (e.g., `N:`) refer to an *existing* drive** (even though no *other* components are required to exist; see [GitHub issue #4386](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4386) for a discussion of this behavior, which is still present as of PowerShell (Core) 7.4):

***Pragmatically*** speaking, you can simply **use *string concatenation / interpolation*** to join your path components:

```bash
# Sample components.
$dir = 'N:\foo'; $file = 'bar'

# OPTION 1: String concatenation
$joinedPath = $dir + '\' + $file

# OPTION 2: String interpolation
$joinedPath = "$dir\$file"

OPTION 3: With an open-ended number of path components stored in array.
$components = $dir, 'sub', $file
$joinedPath = $components -join '\'
```

While, depending on the input components, this can result in accidentally *duplicated* path separators (e.g., `N:\foo\\bar`), this is usually *not* a problem, because the file-system APIs treat such duplicates as a single separator; that is, `N:\foo\\bar` is treated the same as `N:\foo\bar`.

If you want to avoid duplicated separators, see the solution in the next section.

---

**To more fully emulate `Join-Path`**, which involves **removing accidentally *duplicated* separators and *normalizing* them to the platform-native form** (e.g., on Windows, `/` -> `\`), use the following:

```bash
$dir = 'N:\foo'; $file = 'bar.txt'
$components = $dir, $file

$joinedPath = 
  ($components -join '\') -replace '(?!^)[\\/]+', [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar
```

Explanation of the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) and [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation:

- `[\\/]` matches a single `\` or `/`, and `+` matches *one or more* consecutive instances, so as to match *duplicated* path separators too; they are later replaced with a *single*, *platform-native* separator (`[IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar`).
- `(?!^)` is a *negative lookahead assertion* (`(?!…)`) that ensures that `\\` (or `//`) at the *start* (`^`) of the path is preserved as such, so as to support *UNC* paths.

To wrap this up in a **(very simple) function, `join-AnyPath`**:

```bash
function join-AnyPath {
  ($args -join '\') -replace '(?!^)[\\/]+', [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar
}

# Sample call
join-AnyPath N:\dir\ /foo/ bar.txt
```

The above yields `N:\dir\foo\bar.txt` (on Windows).

---

Note:

- [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) points out that there's also the [`[IO.Path]::Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.Combine) .NET method, but while it doesn't require that a drive exist either, its behavior differs from `Join-Path` with respect to how `\`-prefixed components are handled, which can lead to surprising results: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37782461/45375).

Answer (score 3):

With thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038337/powershell-resolve-path-that-might-not-exist) from [x0n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6920/x0n)
I use the Combine() method from the type [System.Management.Automation.PathIntrinsics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pathintrinsics?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0).

It also works with PSDrives and doesn't have the drawback of the .NET [IO.Path]::Combine() method:

```
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.Combine('C:\test1', 'test2')
```

Output:

```
C:\test1\test2
```

Sample with custom PSDrive:

```
New-PSDrive -Name Temp -PSProvider filesystem -Root F:\Temp\
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.Combine('Temp:\test1', 'test2')
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.Combine('Temp:\test1', '\test2')
```

Output:

```
Temp:\test1\test2
Temp:\test1\test2
```